# email body format using powershell

Tags: powershell

I've a working code which searches service1 in one set of servers and service2 in another set of servers. Below is the code. I'm appending to text file and sending it as attachment. Now i'm planning to write this output in mail body in tabular format.

```
$date = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy-hh-mm"

$AllTestServers = {server1.company.com server2.company.com server3.company.com server4.company.com server5.company.com server6.company.com server7.company.com server8.company.com server9.company.com server10.company.com}
$AllProdServers = {prod1.company.com prod2.company.com prod3.company.com prod4.company.com prod5.company.com prod6.company.com prod7.company.com prod8.company.com prod9.company.com prod10.company.com }


$Testservers = $AllTestServers -Split(" ")

For ($i=0; $i -lt $Testservers.Count; $i++) 
{
    $status = Get-Service -Name <serviceName1> -computername $$Testservers[$i] | Select -ExpandProperty Status

    Write-output `r`n $Testservers[$i] ": $status" | Out-File C:\Test\TestServers_$date.txt -Append - -NoNewline
}

$Prodservers = $AllProdServers -Split(" ")

For ($i=0; $i -lt $Prodservers.Count; $i++) 
{
    $status = Get-Service -Name <serviceName2> -computername $Prodservers[$i] | Select -ExpandProperty Status

    Write-output `r`n $Prodservers[$i] ": $status" | Out-File C:\Test\Prodservers_$date.txt -Append - -NoNewline
}
```

Any help?

Comment: You would have to either do a `foreach` line and manually create a HTML table, in an HTML formatted email for nice looking emails, or use `ConvertTo-Html` to more easily convert the objects into HTML that can be emailed.

Comment: It's a bit to much to explain here, but search for Bootstrap-Email, this CSS code can be used in emails to make them look nice, they also provide an HTML template.

Adjust the HTML Template, and then use REPLACE for example to add your HTML Table inside the HTML Template

To create an HTML Table you can use [Array]$Objects | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment